# size of the central directory in zip64 format

Tags: zip

I'm trying to make a zip library for my JS project. But I'm having trouble with Zip64. Regular zip works fine.

Reading the appnote for zip doesn't make me any wiser. In the end of central directory field for Zip64 there is a place to put the "size of the central directory". What does this mean? Is it the total sum of bytes for all central headers including or excluding the end of central directory field?

Can someone help me? The specification is very diffuse.

Comment: "diffuse" is not the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How could you have gotten it working for "regular" zip files without knowing this? Setting aside the Zip64 extensions, the end of central directory record has four bytes for the "size of the central directory". If you got it working for "regular" zip files, then you *already know* that that size is for the central directory only, as it is named. The end of central directory record is a different, separate thing, and doesn't even need to be adjacent to the central directory.

In the case of Zip64, where the offset of the central directory or its size do not fit in four bytes, or there are more than 64K entries, then that size is stored instead in eight bytes in a different structure called the Zip64 end of central directory record. That record is found via the Zip64 end of central directory locator that immediately precedes the end of central directory record. In that case that eight-byte central directory size is again the central directory size, period. None of the Zip64 end of central directory record, the Zip64 end of central directory locator, nor the end of central directory are part of the central directory.

And, by the way, the specification is quite clear. Section 4.3.12 shows the central directory structure. Nowhere in that section do you find any of those other records or fields.

Comment: Im forcing zip64 on all my zip files. Is it because i set 0xfffffff in the EOCD when the  value is not bigger.

Comment: Is _what_ because? You need to provide more information in your question (not in comments) about what, exactly, you're doing, and what "trouble", exactly, you are having?